# Nw.js display pdf in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, nw.js

I'm trying to build an app with Web2Executable software. My html package work fine in Chrome and Firefox, but when I create the exe file, it works except for the iframe with pdf in it.

I'm using the jquery library Featherlight for the popup.

This is the result:
[image]

A simple grey box.

The only warning in the console say: "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf"

Maybe I need to include some plugins?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the pdf problem in the exe using a previous version of NW.js (0.22.3 instead of 0.23.1). Now it works